# ¿como poder extraer datos de una lista ? en python

Tags: python

soy nuevo en esta comunidad espero me puedan colaborar estoy tratando de obtner los datos de una lista xDmas especificamente tengo una lista con N datos y requiero que cada 20 datos tomarlos y restarles cierta cantidad

```
`valor = float(input('ingresar el valor inicial: '))
i = 0 #contar los dias
N = 250
X = 0.7 # porcentaje

#porcentaje
p = X*valor/100
print(p)


lista = []  # lista vacia para guardar los elementos
for i in range(N):
    valor = valor+p
    lista.append(valor)
        
#cada 20 dias le restamos 5000

print(lista)
len(lista)`
```

Comment: Para obtener datos específicos de una lista solo hace falta poner la posición del elemento que quieres al lado del nombre de la lista, algo así: lista[0], lo cual equivale al primer elemento de la lista, si en lugar de poner un 0, pones un 1, equivale al segundo elemento de la lista, y así sucesivamente. https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-listas.html

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes el codigo para generar una lista:

```
lista = []  # lista vacia para guardar los elementos
for i in range(N):
  valor = valor+p
  lista.append(valor)
```

[Aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/) tienes una guia para recorrer listas, de los cuales esta me parece que puede ayudar a tu problema:

```
# Python3 code to iterate over a list
list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

# Getting length of list
length = len(list)
i = 0

# Iterating using while loop
while i < length:
   print(list[i])
   i += 1
```

Implementando algo rapido con el codigo que propones sería algo así:

```
#cada 20 dias le restamos 5000
length = len(lista)
i = 0
  
# Iterating using while loop
while i < length:
    print(i ,": ", lista[i])
    lista[i]=lista[i]-5000
    i=i+20
```

Comment: no utilices palabras reservadas como nombre de variables, eso sobre-escribe el objeto

Comment: Muchas Gracias me sirvió de Mucho X)

Comment: @Christian creo que length no es una palabra reservada en python.  o ¿Cuál sería la palabra?  https://betterprogramming.pub/all-33-reserved-keywords-in-python-98e55f6c8ded

Comment: Estás reemplazando el constructor list con una lista.

Comment: Exactamente lo que dijo DanteS., la palabra reservada es `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Esta función recibe una lista y le resta una cantidad cada tantos elementos:

```
def restarcada(lista, salto, valor):
    for i in range(0, len(lista), salto):
        lista[i] -= valor
```

Para recorrerla se usa la versión extendida de `range(valor_inicial, valor_final, paso)`, que nos permite avanzar por la lista dando saltos.

#### Demo

Dada la lista `[0, 1, 2, 3, ... 19]`, restamos 10 a los elementos cada 4 posiciones:

```
def restarcada(lista, salto, valor):
    for i in range(0, len(lista), salto):
        lista[i] -= valor

lis = list(range(20))
restarcada(lis, 4, 10)
print(lis)
```

produce:

```
[-10, 1, 2, 3, -6, 5, 6, 7, -2, 9, 10, 11, 2, 13, 14, 15, 6, 17, 18, 19]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: excelente de verdad muchas gracias x)